# Discord Bot sending more than one message

Tags: discord.py

So I am creating a simple bot that detects when somebody joins a server and when somebody leaves the server.
I added a command to show people's avatars, but any time I do it, or when somebody joins or leaves, it sends the message more than once.
I've searched and I can't find the problem.
Can you guys help me?

Here's my code

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready")

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="entradas")
    await channel.send(f"{member} is new on the server, everyone say hi")

    show_avatar = discord.Embed(color = discord.Color.blue())
    show_avatar.set_image(url="{}".format(member.avatar_url))

    await channel.send(embed=show_avatar)


@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name="saidas")
    await channel.send(f"{member} left the server, press F to pay respects")



@client.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member):



    show_avatar = discord.Embed(color = discord.Color.blue())
    show_avatar.set_image(url="{}".format(member.avatar_url))

    await ctx.send(embed=show_avatar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if you are running 2 bots.

If you are running your bot on Linux with screen, simply check with

```
screen -ls
```

on windows, just check the task-manager and look under something like Python.

It's btw possible to have the same bot running twice.